# Use new Deployment Job in Azure DevOps. Can't find artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I need to deploy an Asp.Net Core Application to Azure WebApp using Azure Devops.

I have the following working Azure-Pipelines YAML file:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  version: '0.2.0'

stages:

- stage: 'Stage1'

  jobs:

  # Previous Jobs like Build, Test, ...

  - job: 'Publish'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    dependsOn: 'Test'
    steps:

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Publish'
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        displayName: 'Deploy'
        inputs:
          package: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/App.Api.zip'
          azureSubscription: 'MyName.Azure'
          appType: 'Web App On Windows'
          webAppName: 'myname-api'
```

This works fine but I would like to use the new [Deployment Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops).

I removed the 'Deploy' task and added it as a new Deployment Job after the 'Publish' job:

```
  - deployment: DeployJob
    dependsOn: 'Publish'
    pool:
      vmImage: Ubuntu-16.04
    environment: production
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              package: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/App.Api.zip'
              azureSubscription: 'MyName.Azure'
              appType: 'Web App On Windows'
              webAppName: 'myname-api'
```

You can see that the 'AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4' is the same as before.

But now I get the following error when I run the pipeline:

```
Download artifact to: /home/vsts/work/1/
Could not find any pipeline artifacts in the build.
```

What am I missing? How to fix this?

Comment: Hello Miguel, I am having same issue, if I add DownloadBuildArtifacts@0 step it works fine, but based on documentation it says if job is "deployment" like yours you don't have to downnload artifacts explicitly but it's not working without downloading, did you figure it out to make it work without explicitly downloading the artifacts during deployment job ?

Answer (score 8):

I've struggled with this all day myself, until stumbling into a solution. It seems there are a few default "helper" tasks that get bundled into the jobs, and the deployment jobs have a default download task that gets added. I'm still not sure what it was trying to download in my case, but it was causing the same problem you describe.

Try adding a `- download: none` task to your deployment job's steps, and specifying the tasks explicitly instead. Something like this should work:

```
  - stage: deploy_dev
    displayName: Development environment
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy to Development environment
      environment: myproject-dev
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: none
            - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
              inputs:
                artifactName: $(ArtifactName)
                buildType: 'current'
                downloadType: 'single'
                downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Documentation for the download shortcut can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#download

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've found out that a deployment task will automatically run a DownloadBuildArtifact step, however for some reason it doesn't default to $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) and instead defaults to $(Agent.BuildDirectory)

Comment: This is a little older but wanted to provide clarity.  The deployment job type actually [automatically downloads with a DownloadPipelineArtifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: note the MS are moving to a pipeline tasks and not build tasks. Just to add to the confusion :( - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#migrate-from-build-artifacts

Answer (score 3):

you need use PublishPipelineArtifact@1 instead of PublishBuildArtifacts@1 if you split the deployment. I was struggling this issue a whole day, hope this can help u.

```
  # - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish pipeline Artifacts
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)' 
    artifactName: 'coreapidemo'
```

Comment: The shorthand task `publish` will also work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#publish

Answer (score 2):

Try using $(Pipeline.Workspace) instead.
You should also do what @wenbo wrote in his answer but I think it's not required, the important part here is $(Pipeline.Workspace):

> By default, files are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace)/{artifact}, where artifact is the name of the artifact. The folder structure of the artifact is always preserved.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#downloading-artifacts)

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you're trying to deploy before you publish an artifact.

`dependsOn: 'Publish'`

You need to publish the artifact first. This is the step you have called `Artifact`.

I'd also expect that the package path you have, `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/App.Api.zip`, won't work. It's probably going to be somewhere under `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

Comment: Note that Publish is a Job where the second task is Artifact so I don't think that's the problem. About using $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) or $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) none of them worked.

Answer (score -5):

It seems that the format is not correct in your yaml.

```
dependsOn: 'Publish'
```

You may try to use following instead.

```
dependsOn: Publish
```

Here the dependency should be a job object, not a string. In the expression, if the value is string, it must be single-quoted. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Could you please show the debugging info when the job is working?